# Jquery Datatable warning when adding data: Requested unknown parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**HTML**

```
<table id='students_grid' class='table table-bordered table-striped' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >
       <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th> /*Hidden*/
        <th>Sr. No.</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Parent Code</th> /*Hidden*/
        <th>Parent Name</th>                                    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS Initialisation**

```
$("#students_grid").DataTable({       
"select": {style: 'single'},      
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "data":"studentid",
        "targets": [ 0 ],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
    },
    {
        "data":"parentcode",
        "targets": [ 4 ],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
    }
]
});
```

**Adding data in Table (Called on Button Click)**

```
studenttable = $("#students_grid").DataTable();
studenttable.row.add( [
    $("#studentid").val(),
    $("#srno").val(),
    $("#studentname").val(),            
    $("#address").val(),
    $("#parentcode").val(),
    $("#parentname").text()
]).draw(false);
```

After the add function is called an **warning message is popped up**

> DataTables warning: table id=students_grid - Requested unknown
> parameter 'studentid' for row 0, column 0. For more information about
> this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Although the row gets added in the table this warning keeps popping up with each addition the row value changes with each addition.
How can this warning be avoided?

**UPDATE**
If I remove the `"data"` declaration from the initialisation it does not give the error message. Can this not be done with the `"data"` value

Comment: Are you passing a header row in the json? That would account for the row 0, column 0 value being incorrect.  The answer, I think, depends on the data that is being passed to DataTables

Comment: @KScandrett I am only adding one row at a time header row is already added through HTML page. Even if I try to add static values the warning message is show. In spite of the warning the newly added data does show up in the table.

Comment: You have no named parameters in your data, just values.  So it's never going to find something called 'studentid'.

Comment: AddRow example from their website: `table.row.add( { "name": "Tiger Nixon", "position":  "System Architect" } )`

Comment: I think you can just get rid of the named data `"data":"studentid",` line because you are specifying the column via `"targets": [ 0 ],`.

Comment: Did you read the details on the link it provides?  It's all explained there: *"Parameter is a string.  If {parameter} is shown as a string, this will typically indicate that you have used columns.data or columns.render to pull data **out of an object**"* - but you're passing an array, you need to pass an object: `.row.add({ studentid: $("#studentid").val()...`

Comment: @KScandrett I did get rid of the error when I tried adding the data as `table.row.add( { "studentid": "1", "studentsrno":  "5" } )`. But also had to provide `data` property for each of the columns like `{"data":"studentsrno","targets": [ 1 ]}` inside `columnDefs`
Go ahead and add this along with the answer. I would accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is missing parameter names so you will see that error if you try to reference it by one.

In addition, you're passing it an array when it is expecting an object for a single row or an array of objects for multiple rows.

```js
studenttable.row.add({
  "studentid": $("#studentid").val(),
  "srno": $("#srno").val(),
  "studentname": $("#studentname").val(),
  "address": $("#address").val(),
  "parentcode": $("#parentcode").val(),
  "parentname": $("#parentname").text()
}).draw(false);
```